# Is the second hyphen needed in "user-generated and -mediated"?

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation, suspended-hyphen

Which one of the following is more appropriate?

> ...offers scope for the theoretical integration of teaching, learning, and development with the culturally new **user-generated and mediated** contexts.

Or

> ... by an emphasis on information sharing, collaboration, community building, open data standards, and **user-generated and -mediated** content and applications.

Clearly, in such a situation, should dash be used for the second word?

Comment: You are asking about hyphens, not dashes. British sometimes do not distinguish, but in America there are three common types of horizontal-line characters:  hyphen (-), en dash (–), and em dash (—). _Style guides_ (such as those mentioned by Dead Rat) typically discuss separately the usage of each of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two different example, one with contexts and one with content, but it doesn't matter.  The two compound adjectives mean different things.  "User-generated and mediated" contexts means that the users make the contexts but the mediation is not necessarily performed by users.  "User-generated and -mediated" context means the the contexts are user-generated and user-mediated.

For the latter, consult your manual of style, either the one you've adopted or the one thrust upon you.  I use the *Chicago Manual of Style*, which is silent on the use of suspended hyphens preceding a word.  Amy Einsohn's *The Copyeditor's Handbook* says this usage is "licit but likely to confuse."  I think she's right; be kind to your reader:  "user-genterated and user-mediated contexts."